# Need a javascript to check if the subnet CIDR is in range of VPC

Tags: javascript, regex, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr

[Error Details from AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzXpF.png) Example -

VPC Range as "10.0.0.0/24" with the subnet range as "10.0.38.0/24".So it should throw an alert as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

One first idea would be something like this:

```
vpc='10.0.0.0/24'
range='10.0.0.28/24'
rangeParts=range.split('.')
vpc.split('.')
 .map((value, index) => index >= 3 || value === rangeParts[index])
 .reduce((last, next) => last && next, true)
```

It basically compares the first 3 values to be equal. Would not recommend to use this in production, as there are probably cleaner solutions

Comment: please can you explain the logic here (last 2 lines) so that it can be tested.